# inconsistent pip version in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip

I'm using PyCharm on Windows. I have a project setup for small experiments with algorithms that uses it's own virtual environment. I was trying to install tensorflow and I got an error that I'm running pip 10.0.1 and should upgrade to 18.1, which I did through "File/Settings/Project Interpreter". It now says 18.1. But I'm still getting warnings about using version 10.0.1.

[image: different version of pip]

```
(venv) C:\users\xxx\pycharmprojects\so> pip list
...
pip            10.0.1
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

(venv) C:\users\xxx\pycharmprojects\so>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\xxx\pycharmprojects\so\venv\lib\site-packages (18.1)

(venv) C:\users\xxx\pycharmprojects\so> pip list
...
pip            10.0.1
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

(venv) C:\users\xxx\pycharmprojects\so>python -m pip list
...
pip            18.1
```

Comment: Could you just run `python -m pip list` and share the result?

Comment: added, and it's different from just `pip list`. i understand it even less now

Comment: What is happening is the following: PyCharm has created the virtual env with a given python version and for some reason, I cannot say exactly what it might be right now, the link to `pip` points to the one that is installed system wide, rather than the one in the venv. So just to make sure, when you are using `pip` in virtualenv always add `python -m` in front of it so you know that you are actually calling the virtualenv instance of pip.

P.S. that might be some issue with Windows based installation

Comment: Have you resolved your issue?

Comment: nope. i deleted the venv, upgraded the "main" pip, created new venv and i have the same issue. I give up. I'll probably just stick to linux

Comment: I can confirm Tensorflow installation works correctly under Linux, but could you please do me/us a favour and try running the following commands:


**1.** python3.5 -m venv /some/dir
**2.** cd /some/dir
**3.** ./bin/activate
**4.** python -m pip install --upgrade pip
**5.** python -m pip install --upgrade tensorflow

Comment: i ran (windows equivalents of) your commands in separate empty folder. pip seems to be upgraded but tensorflow doesn't install: `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for tensorflow`

Comment: Oh, here's the problem, you are using python3.7, Tensorflow only supports Python3.5 under Windows. Unfortunately, neither under Windows nor under Linux does Tensorflow support python3.7, the highest you can get to is python3.6 . I can confirm I just installed Tensorflow under Windows using the 64-bit installer of Python3.5.4rc1

Comment: thanks! but are you saying trying to install tensorflow on wrong version of python broke my pip?

Comment: No, nothing broke your pip, you were just executing the wrong pip, this might get a little bit confusing so make sure you specify `python -m` before you call pip so you are sure which installation you are using.

Comment: I have been coding in python for over a year, on linux and mac and never had to use `python -m` for pip commands. is this windows specific problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183894/discussion-between-tenorflyy-and-maiki-bodhisattva).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of discussion, we've got the problem solved.
Here's what was wrong:

1. PyCharm is unable to properly update pip under Windows while using virtualenv (possible bug/issue)
2. The reason why installation of Tensorflow was failing at first place was that it strictly requires Python3.5 under Windows, while the problem occured with Python3.7, so switching to Python3.5 VirtualEnv in PyCharm solved the issue.

NOTE: No pip update was required in order to install Tensroflow with Pycharm + Python3.5 venv

Answer (score 0):

It has happened to me after upgrading to Python 3.7.1 and pip 19.0.3.
It was solved after making sure that both new Python installation folder and corresponding Scripts folder are included in the PATH environment variable prior to creating a new virtual environment for my project.